# Matching variable names with their corresponding values over different databases

Tags: stata

I am trying to import the variable names from an external dataset using a macro, match these names with their corresponding values in the main file and then export results of a looping principal component analysis using `esttab`.

My code looks like this.

```
preserve

forvalue file = 537(3)647 {

    import excel "C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Masterarbeit\Stata12\test/`file'.xls", sheet("Sheet1") firstrow clear

    local x ""
    foreach var of varlist *SA {
        local x `x' `var'
    }

    clear
    restore

    forvalue z = 537(3)647 {
        pca `x' if rMonth < `z'+3, comp(1)
        esttab e(L) using pc`z'.csv, replace
    }
}
```

The command is supposed to cycle through the file defined in the first loop, catch the variable names in the file, match these with the variables and the respective values in the main file (names of the variables are the same) and then perform the `pca`. Afterwards, it is supposed to create a new list of variable names in the next excel file and use these variables in `pca`. In this state the code only works should the values also be in the external datasets.

The problem is, that I can't find a way to match the variable names in the external files with the ones in the mainfile, I only get the error "no variables defined" as the external files consist only of the names of the variables, not the values.

Any advice how I can tell Stata that it should look up the variable names from the external files and use their values for the `pca`?

Edit: before the preserve, my code generates the variables, regresses them on a dependent variable, ranks them according to the t-value and exports them to the files I use to grab the varlist. The code looks like this:

```
. set excelxlsxlargefile on

cd C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Masterarbeit\Stata12\sentiment_6m

. import excel "C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Masterarbeit\Daten\Dataimport\sentiments\Google Query CDX.xlsx", sheet("Tabelle1") firstrow

set more off

gen Month = month( Date)

gen     January     =   1   if  Month   ==  1
gen     February    =   1   if  Month   ==  2
gen     March   =   1   if  Month   ==  3
gen     April   =   1   if  Month   ==  4
gen     May =   1   if  Month   ==  5
gen     June    =   1   if  Month   ==  6
gen     July    =   1   if  Month   ==  7
gen     August  =   1   if  Month   ==  8
gen     September   =   1   if  Month   ==  9
gen     October =   1   if  Month   ==  10
gen     November    =   1   if  Month   ==  11
gen     December    =   1   if  Month   ==  12
replace     January     =   0   if  January     ==  .
replace     February    =   0   if  February    ==  .
replace     March   =   0   if  March   ==  .
replace     April   =   0   if  April   ==  .
replace     May =   0   if  May ==  .
replace     June    =   0   if  June    ==  .
replace     July    =   0   if  July    ==  .
replace     August  =   0   if  August  ==  .
replace     September   =   0   if  September   ==  .
replace     October =   0   if  October ==  .
replace     November    =   0   if  November    ==  .
replace     December    =   0   if  December    ==  .


foreach var of varlist *_qry{  
sum `var', meanonly
local mu =r(mean)
reg `var' January  February March April May June July August September October November December, nocons
predict double `var'SA, residual
replace `var'SA=`var'SA+`mu'
egen sd = sd(`var'SA)
replace `var'SA=`var'SA/sd
drop sd
drop `var'
}



* BIG LOOP *

generate double rMonth = mofd( Date)
global tflist ""

forvalue y = 537(3)647{


foreach var of varlist *SA{
reg MidCDX `var' if rMonth<=`y'
tempfile tfcur
parmest, idstr("`var'") saving(`"`tfcur'"', replace) flis(tflist) 
}


* Concatenate files into memory (REPLACING THE OLD DATA) *
preserve
clear
append using $tflist
sencode idstr, gene(xvar)
lab var xvar "X-variable"
keybygen xvar, gene(parmseq)
drop if parm=="_cons"
egen rank = rank (-t)
gsort -t
drop if rank>40
save `y', replace
export excel xvar t using `y', firstrow(variables) replace
foreach TF in $tflist {
erase `"`TF'"'
}
global tflist ""
restore

}
```

Comment: Meta-comment: You are posting the code for a large chunk of an entire project. That doesn't seem to be out of order, but the questions that work best here are focused on a single point raised by programming that might interest several other people. I've got to say that the chance that anyone wants to do exactly what you want is essentially zero.

Comment: The whole `gen` - `replace` block can be substituted for one line provided you are willing to sacrifice month names as variable names: `tabulate Month, gen(month)`. Variables would then be `month1`, `month2`, ...

Comment: Valid point Nick, I just posted the code as I understood that Roberto wanted to know what I do before. And thanks for all the helpfull comments to both of you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this example helps:

```
clear all
set more off

/*
load two example MS Excel files with var names only and accumulate var names in a local.
files are named varfile.xls and varfile2.xls
*/

foreach i in "" "2" {

    import excel "/home/roberto/Desktop/stata_tests/varfile`i'.xls", firstrow clear

    * get var names
    quietly ds

    * save var names in local
    local myvars `myvars' `r(varlist)'
}

* load database that contains vars and values
sysuse auto, clear

* do pca
pca `myvars'

/*
varfile.xls contains variables "weight" and "price"
varfile2.xls contains variables "mpg" and "length"
*/
```

`ds` does the trick here because it saves the names of the variables picked up in the MS Excel sheet and stores the result in `r(varlist)`. See `help ds` and `help saved results` (or `help stored results`). Afterwards, we load a "complete" database and use the stored variable names with `pca`.

The MS Excel files look like this:

[image]

This, I think, answers the specific question you pose.

### Edit

Looking closer at your code, I'm not sure the problem is related to matching variable names in the complete database, but rather some problem with the way you set up `preserve` and `restore`. Instead of using that set of commands, try simply loading the complete database when you need it (with `use`).

What do you have before the `preserve`? Where does your error appear? Please post more code. A reproducible example would help.

### Edit 2

My conjecture now is that you have *nothing* before the `preserve`, so when you `restore`, you're just setting the slate clean; you are restoring a blank database. Therefore, trying `pca <somevar>` gives you:

```
no variables defined
r(111);
```

`preserve` preserves the data as it is just *before* the command is issued.

Comment: Roberto, thanks a lot for your help! Your command does seem to do the trick in matching the variable names with their time series in the main file. There is only one aspect which prevents the code from giving me the desired results. For every loop in which a -pca- is executed, there should be a different varlist the code should search for, thus the list is not accumulative as it is in your code. Eg in your example the -pca- should first be executed with "weight" and "price" and then with "mpg" and "length". I tried macro drop `myvars' but it did not work. I added code in my question.

Comment: Ok, figured out how to drop the local by using `local myvars` in the end of the loop. But somehow the loop now only takes the variables from the firt file and not the others. Will look into it.

Comment: If you don't want to accumulate variables just substitute ``local myvars `myvars' `r(varlist)'`` for ``local myvars `r(varlist)'``.

Answer (score 2):

Personal comment: There is too much code here for me to want to try and absorb what you are trying to do. I comment only on some details of technique.

This block of code

`gen     January     =   1   if  Month   ==  1
gen     February    =   1   if  Month   ==  2
gen     March   =   1   if  Month   ==  3
gen     April   =   1   if  Month   ==  4
gen     May =   1   if  Month   ==  5
gen     June    =   1   if  Month   ==  6
gen     July    =   1   if  Month   ==  7
gen     August  =   1   if  Month   ==  8
gen     September   =   1   if  Month   ==  9
gen     October =   1   if  Month   ==  10
gen     November    =   1   if  Month   ==  11
gen     December    =   1   if  Month   ==  12
replace     January     =   0   if  January     ==  .
replace     February    =   0   if  February    ==  .
replace     March   =   0   if  March   ==  .
replace     April   =   0   if  April   ==  .
replace     May =   0   if  May ==  .
replace     June    =   0   if  June    ==  .
replace     July    =   0   if  July    ==  .
replace     August  =   0   if  August  ==  .
replace     September   =   0   if  September   ==  .
replace     October =   0   if  October ==  .
replace     November    =   0   if  November    ==  .
replace     December    =   0   if  December    ==  .`

can be rewritten like this

```
tokenize "`c(Months)'"
forval j = 1/12 { 
    gen ``j'' = Month == `j' 
}
```

The month names January to December are wired into `c(Months)`.

```
sum `var', meanonly
local mu =r(mean)
reg `var' January  February March April May June July August September October November December, nocons
predict double `var'SA, residual
replace `var'SA=`var'SA+`mu'
egen sd = sd(`var'SA)
replace `var'SA=`var'SA/sd
drop sd
```

can be shortened to

```
reg `var' January-December, nocons
predict double `var'SA, residual
sum `var' 
replace `var'SA = (`var'SA + r(mean)) / r(sd)
```

Note that it is not a good idea to create an entire variable holding just the SD. That cancels out any time savings from using `summarize, meanonly`.

I don't comment here on what you are trying to do statistically, adding the mean and then dividing by the SD.

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer trumps the first part by pointing to `tabulate` with the `generate()` option.

Comment: Yes thanks for the hint Nick, the mean was definitely out of place there. Erased that one.

Answer (score 1):

@Roberto Ferrer is addressing your main problem, which hinges on comparing variable names across files. I add a detail on the use of local macros and wildcard syntax.

```
local x ""
foreach var of varlist *SA {
    local x `x' `var'
}
```

is a long way to get

```
unab x : *SA
```